# How to salvage data from faulty usb drive

Tags: data-recovery, usb-flash-drive, data-transfer

I have a small 64GB usb thumb drive that has valuable files on it, but I can't really get everything off of it.
It's recognized by my OS (Manjaro Linux), I can see the contents and even copy some files over to my harddrive, but it'll always unmount itself after a while.
The time before this happens seems to vary between a couple seconds and a minute or so.
This is the case regardless which USB port I plug it into and on two different PCs.
I figure the drive itself is broken - can anyone help getting a better idea of why it does that and maybe how to fix?

UPDATE:
I checked the syslog, here are the kernel messages, I hope helpful:

```
13.01.22 13:58  audit   type=1100 audit(1642078683.318:146): pid=8910 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/4 res=success'
13.01.22 13:58  audit   type=1101 audit(1642078683.318:147): pid=8910 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/4 res=success'
13.01.22 13:58  audit   type=1103 audit(1642078683.318:148): pid=8910 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/4 res=success'
13.01.22 13:58  audit   type=1105 audit(1642078683.318:149): pid=8910 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/4 res=success'
13.01.22 13:58  audit   type=1106 audit(1642078683.328:150): pid=8910 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:session_close grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/4 res=success'
13.01.22 13:58  audit   type=1104 audit(1642078683.328:151): pid=8910 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/4 res=success'
13.01.22 13:58  audit   type=1100 audit(1642078683.511:152): pid=8913 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/4 res=success'
13.01.22 13:58  audit   type=1101 audit(1642078683.511:153): pid=8913 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/4 res=success'
13.01.22 13:58  audit   type=1103 audit(1642078683.511:154): pid=8913 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/4 res=success'
13.01.22 13:58  audit   type=1105 audit(1642078683.511:155): pid=8913 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/4 res=success'
13.01.22 13:59  usb 1-3 new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
13.01.22 13:59  usb 1-3 New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=16a3, bcdDevice= 1.10
13.01.22 13:59  usb 1-3 New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
13.01.22 13:59  usb 1-3 Product: DT microDuo 3.0
13.01.22 13:59  usb 1-3 Manufacturer: Kingston
13.01.22 13:59  usb 1-3 SerialNumber: 408D5CE4B641B181391310B3
13.01.22 13:59  usb-storage 1-3 .0: USB Mass Storage device detected
13.01.22 13:59  scsi host2  usb-storage 1-3:1.0
13.01.22 13:59  scsi 2  :0:0: Direct-Access Kingston DT microDuo 3.0 PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
13.01.22 13:59  sd 2    :0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
13.01.22 13:59  sd 2    :0:0: [sdc] 121110528 512-byte logical blocks: (62.0 GB/57.8 GiB)
13.01.22 13:59  sd 2    :0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is on
13.01.22 13:59  sd 2    :0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 45 00 80 00
13.01.22 13:59  sd 2    :0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
13.01.22 13:59   sdc    sdc1
13.01.22 13:59  sd 2    :0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
13.01.22 13:59  sd 2    :0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 45 00 00 00
13.01.22 13:59  sd 2    :0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
13.01.22 13:59  FAT-fs (sdc1)   Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
13.01.22 14:00  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, corrupted directory (invalid entries)
13.01.22 14:00  FAT-fs (sdc1)   Filesystem has been set read-only
13.01.22 14:00  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, corrupted directory (invalid entries)
13.01.22 14:00  VFS Lookup of '. 1' in vfat sdc1 would have caused loop
13.01.22 14:00  VFS Lookup of 'n`' in vfat sdc1 would have caused loop
13.01.22 14:00  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start feedc612)
13.01.22 14:00  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 4f4be400)
13.01.22 14:00  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start fff96bc9)
13.01.22 14:00  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 8100ac7d)
13.01.22 14:00  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start dfdcafcf)
13.01.22 14:00  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 8b64cbd3)
13.01.22 14:00  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start fcae00ff)
13.01.22 14:00  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start bc005f0b)
13.01.22 14:00  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 25bff767)
13.01.22 14:00  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start f2cb4142)
13.01.22 14:02  VFS Lookup of '. 1' in vfat sdc1 would have caused loop
13.01.22 14:02  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, corrupted directory (invalid entries)
13.01.22 14:02  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, corrupted directory (invalid entries)
13.01.22 14:02  fat_get_cluster 18 callbacks suppressed
13.01.22 14:02  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start feedc612)
13.01.22 14:02  VFS Lookup of 'n`' in vfat sdc1 would have caused loop
13.01.22 14:02  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 4f4be400)
13.01.22 14:02  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start fff96bc9)
13.01.22 14:02  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 8100ac7d)
13.01.22 14:02  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start dfdcafcf)
13.01.22 14:02  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 8b64cbd3)
13.01.22 14:02  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start fcae00ff)
13.01.22 14:02  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start bc005f0b)
13.01.22 14:02  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start 25bff767)
13.01.22 14:02  FAT-fs (sdc1)   error, fat_get_cluster: invalid start cluster (i_pos 0, start f2cb4142)
13.01.22 14:03  usb 1-3 reset high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
13.01.22 14:03  usb 1-3 device descriptor read/64, error -110
13.01.22 14:03  usb 1-3 device firmware changed
13.01.22 14:03  sd 2    :0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=16s
13.01.22 14:03  sd 2    :0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 02 8a 80 c0 00 00 f0 00
13.01.22 14:03  print_req_error 1614 callbacks suppressed
13.01.22 14:03  blk_update_request  I/O error, dev sdc, sector 42631360 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x84700 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
13.01.22 14:03  usb 1-3 USB disconnect, device number 8
13.01.22 14:03  sd 2    :0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
13.01.22 14:03  sd 2    :0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 02 8a 81 b0 00 00 f0 00
13.01.22 14:03  blk_update_request  I/O error, dev sdc, sector 42631600 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x84700 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
13.01.22 14:03  blk_update_request  I/O error, dev sdc, sector 42631840 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
13.01.22 14:03  blk_update_request  I/O error, dev sdc, sector 42631872 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x84700 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
13.01.22 14:03  blk_update_request  I/O error, dev sdc, sector 42632112 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x84700 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
13.01.22 14:03  blk_update_request  I/O error, dev sdc, sector 42632352 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
13.01.22 14:03  blk_update_request  I/O error, dev sdc, sector 42631360 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
13.01.22 14:03  blk_update_request  I/O error, dev sdc, sector 42631360 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
13.01.22 14:03  usb 1-3 new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
13.01.22 14:03  usb 1-3 New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=5500, bcdDevice= 1.10
13.01.22 14:03  usb 1-3 New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
13.01.22 14:03  usb 1-3 Product: 2307 Boot ROM
13.01.22 14:03  usb 1-3 Manufacturer: Phison
13.01.22 14:03  usb-storage 1-3 .0: USB Mass Storage device detected
13.01.22 14:03  scsi host3  usb-storage 1-3:1.0
13.01.22 14:03  scsi 3  :0:0: Direct-Access 2307 PRAM 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
13.01.22 14:03  sd 3    :0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
13.01.22 14:03  sd 3    :0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: It's as good as dead, I'm afraid.

Comment: Time to mention… again… that storing data in only one location is just an accident waiting to happen. On something as fragile as a USB stick or SD card is just asking for it to happen sooner.  Take it to a data recovery company.

Comment: When in doubt, you could try a [flash drive data recovery service](https://drivesaversdatarecovery.com/data-recovery-services/devices-supported/removable-media-data-recovery/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get data off of a damaged thumb drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/123606/how-can-i-get-data-off-of-a-damaged-thumb-drive)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, it does, iff everyone agrees this is, in fact, damaged hardware and nothing can be done software-side to repair it...?